# Load PDF data Inside Android Application

Tags: android, pdf

Is there anyway to load PDF from bytes which are in PDF format in android? I am using Android PDF writer (http://coderesearchlabs.com/androidpdfwriter/ ) to create PDF data.

I do not want to save the file and then open it using Acrobat Reader/ Some PDF Reader. Neither I can upload it to google docs etc and then open it in a web view.

I directly want to show created PDF data to the user.

I have tried many libraries like, MuPdf, VUDroid etc but they all require to save a file and then open it using these libraries.

EDIT:

I can generate PDF and save it in internal storage, but the problem is that I dont want to save it in memory. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
public class PDFWriterDemo extends Activity {   

    TextView mText;

    private String generateHelloWorldPDF() {
        PDFWriter mPDFWriter = new PDFWriter(PaperSize.FOLIO_WIDTH, PaperSize.FOLIO_HEIGHT);                                    

        // note that to make this images snippet work
        // you have to uncompress the assets.zip file
        // included into your project assets folder
        AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
        try {
            Bitmap xoiPNG = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mngr.open("border.png"));
            Bitmap xoiJPG = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mngr.open("star.jpg"));
            Bitmap xoiBMP1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mngr.open("bit1.bmp"));
            Bitmap xoiBMP8 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mngr.open("bit8.bmp"));
            Bitmap xoiBMP24 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mngr.open("bit24.bmp"));
            mPDFWriter.addImage(400, 600, xoiPNG, Transformation.DEGREES_315_ROTATION);
            mPDFWriter.addImage(300, 500, xoiJPG);
            mPDFWriter.addImage(200, 400, 135, 75, xoiBMP24);
            mPDFWriter.addImage(150, 300, 130, 70, xoiBMP8);
            mPDFWriter.addImageKeepRatio(100, 200, 50, 25, xoiBMP8);
            mPDFWriter.addImageKeepRatio(50, 100, 30, 25, xoiBMP1, Transformation.DEGREES_270_ROTATION);
            mPDFWriter.addImageKeepRatio(25, 50, 30, 25, xoiBMP1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);
        mPDFWriter.addRawContent("1 0 0 rg\n");
        mPDFWriter.addTextAsHex(70, 50, 12, "68656c6c6f20776f726c6420286173206865782921");
        mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.COURIER, StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING);
        mPDFWriter.addRawContent("0 0 0 rg\n");
        mPDFWriter.addText(30, 90, 10, "© CRL", Transformation.DEGREES_270_ROTATION);

        mPDFWriter.newPage();
        mPDFWriter.addRawContent("[] 0 d\n");
        mPDFWriter.addRawContent("1 w\n");
        mPDFWriter.addRawContent("0 0 1 RG\n");
        mPDFWriter.addRawContent("0 1 0 rg\n");
        mPDFWriter.addRectangle(40, 50, 280, 50);
        mPDFWriter.addText(85, 75, 18, "Code Research Laboratories");

        mPDFWriter.newPage();
        mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.COURIER_BOLD);
        mPDFWriter.addText(150, 150, 14, "http://coderesearchlabs.com");
        mPDFWriter.addLine(150, 140, 270, 140);

        int pageCount = mPDFWriter.getPageCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
            mPDFWriter.setCurrentPage(i);
            mPDFWriter.addText(10, 10, 8, Integer.toString(i + 1) + " / " + Integer.toString(pageCount));
        }

        String s = mPDFWriter.asString();
        return s;
    }

    private void outputToScreen(int viewID, String pdfContent) {
        mText = (TextView) this.findViewById(viewID);
        mText.setText(pdfContent);
    }

    private void outputToFile(String fileName, String pdfContent, String encoding) {
        Log.i("NAUMAN", ""+getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
        File newFile = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName);
        try {
            newFile.createNewFile();
            try {
                FileOutputStream pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                pdfFile.write(pdfContent.getBytes());
                pdfFile.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            //

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String pdfcontent = generateHelloWorldPDF();
        outputToScreen(R.id.text, pdfcontent);
        outputToFile("helloworld.pdf",pdfcontent,"ISO-8859-1");
    }
```

}

Comment: If you are not going to display the PDF in a third-party app, why are you using a PDF in the first place? Generate your output as HTML/CSS/JS and render it in a `WebView`.

Comment: I was looking something similar to iOS, it can take PDF data and display it. I have to do similar task in my android app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't display PDFs with standard Android Widgets, but there are several libraries you can use, for example [MuPDF](https://github.com/muennich/mupdf) (free) or [qPDF](http://www.qoppa.com/android/pdfsdk/) (commercial).

Comment: I have used these libraries as well but they require pdf file and I do not want to save pdf file in memory due to some security risk. Is there any other possible option?

Comment: qPDF also works with a InputStream or a String representing the PDF. Your `mPDFWriter.asString();` should work with this.